# Select command inside XML

Tags: xml, vb.net, nlog

Is it possible to write a SQL Select command inside an XML file and store each field of the select result separately?

PS: I am going to use NLog to send an email (only using NLog) in vb.net , and NLog gets the required information for emailing from XML file, now i am going to get this information from data base in XML and then use it by NLog in vb.net

This is a NLog XML file which inserts a file into a database, I am going to do the reverse operation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
    autoReload="true"
    throwExceptions="false"
    internalLogLevel="Off">
<targets>
<target
    xsi:type="Database"
    name="d"
    dbProvider="System.Data.SqlClient"
    connectionStringName="DefaultConnection"
    commandText="EXEC NLogErrorLogInsert @errordate, @source, @level, @message">
<parameter name="@errordate" layout="${date:universalTime=true:format=s}" />
<parameter name="@source" layout="${machinename}" />
<parameter name="@level" layout="${level:uppercase=true}" />
<parameter name="@message" layout="${message}" />
</target>
</targets>
<rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Warn" writeTo="d" />
</rules>
</nlog>
```

Comment: What do you mean with " store each field of the select result separately?"?

Comment: Think your application has to do the reading of logevents from the database manually, and then send the logevents into an NLog-logger that targets a mail-target.

Comment: @Julian like if we select name , family name, ID of one person , the result of each field is stored seprately in a variable in XML.

Comment: @RolfKristensen
sending to the Nlog logger, you mean storing the information in XML with the same name of Logger? 
so what about the credential information?

Comment: @MoslemTeymoori Yes you need to save enough information in the database, so you at a later point can recreate a NLog LogEventInfo that contains enough information to send a nice email. Again your english is not easy to understand, so maybe I'm misunderstanding your question completely.

Comment: @RolfKristensen

Comment: @RolfKristensen  yes you are right , i do not speak english very well, and i'm really sorry .
Thank you for your help, I solved it. 
The only point is that while getting the information(username, email, password, port number, ...) from the database and having them stored in the XML config file, for sending the email,  I don't want to show the credential information for example Password in the XML file. or atleast hide them in the XML, is there anyway for doing that ?